# SQLite: making foreign key unique

Tags: sqlite

I am using SQLite 3.8.11 for Mac OS X app .
My goal is to create a table and then inside reference some field in other table.
For example:

```
CREATE TABLE artist(
  artistid    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  artistname  TEXT
);
CREATE TABLE track(
  FOREIGN KEY(trackartist) REFERENCES artist(artistid)
);
```

However, I want to insert ***trackartist*** into *track* so that each row will contain unique ***trackartist*** value. In case the ***trackartist*** value is already inside the *track* - the new value must be ignored. 
How can I do that in this setting? 
UPDATE OR IGNORE command seems not working, values are duplicated.

Comment: Why use SQLite directly?  At least use some kind of wrapper, like FMDB.   Or just use CoreData as it handles relationships, change management, validation and a slew of other hard problems for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this would work?

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO track (trackartist) VALUES '123'
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM track WHERE trackartist="123");
```

See [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) for detailed documentation.

EDIT:
Correct syntax is following:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO track (trackartist) SELECT '123' WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM track WHERE trackartist="123");
```

Comment: the values are still being duplicated?

Comment: Syntax is slightly incorrect, but seems to be working, thanks. Expected syntax is something like: INSERT OR REPLACE INTO track (trackartist) SELECT '123'
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM track WHERE trackartist="123");

Comment: oh thanks, updated my answer to include your correction

Comment: It's far easier to simply specify that `trackartist` must be `UNIQUE`.

Comment: @Rob is it possible to do this in sqlite once the table has already been created?

Comment: I'm not sure, but constraints should be part of the table definition, not enforced by adding `WHERE` clauses in the `INSERT` statements.

Answer (score 6):

These are two separate issues: The `FOREIGN KEY` specifies merely that the value being inserted must exist in the other table, but doesn't specify how many times it may appear in this table. The `UNIQUE` constraint, on the other hand, requires that the value may not appear more than once in this table.

I'm not sure if it makes sense with the "artist-track" model, but let's imagine that you really wanted to specify that an artist can't have more than one track. You would therefore specify not only that `trackartist` references `artist(artistid)`, but also that it is `UNIQUE`:

```
CREATE TABLE track(
  trackname TEXT,
  trackartist INTEGER UNIQUE,
  FOREIGN KEY(trackartist) REFERENCES artist(artistid)
);
```

Comment: So this is one way to implement one to one relationship, foreign key & unique